# How to conduct a musical havdalah service?

Tags: music, havdalah

On a Jewish listserve that I subscribe to, somebody posted the following question:

> Does anyone have the music and an outline for the havdalah service? I
>   want to do havdalah before an event for the young professionals group
>   I am part of.

How should I respond to her message?

Comment: What is your goal?  Are you looking for appropriate music?  Are you trying to discourage or alter the event in some way?

Comment: If they're good enough they can try [this](http://youtu.be/T61WDTia3HI)

Answer (score 3):

Many use [the popular melody by Debbie Friedman](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1K4yPaV_JBY). Its simple, easily found in shireinu or other sources and has lots of 'lai-lai-lai" for those who might not know or remember the words or are too lost in thought about the young professional across the room to have any kvanah...

Comment: Those lai-lai-lais can also be extended easily for as long as it takes to pass spice boxes through the crowd.

Answer (score 2):

At least the introductory portion "Hinei el yeshuati" in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oKtJ1IEWsYo) is a common tune used as camps, some yeshivas, etc. While they say the brachot in this video, some continue that tune.

Comment: I love the music of Reb Shlomo!  Thanks so much for that video.

Answer (score 0):

We have used in my shul tunes from "Like a Braided Candle - Songs for Havdalah" by Gail Javitt.  I have it in CD form.  It is available from amazon.  The tunes are easy to learn.